# PLS-00201 when calling executing PLSQL from java

Tags: java, oracle, stored-procedures

When i am trying to execute the procedure in Oracle itself, it works fine. But when i call the same procedure from java, i am getting PLS-00201 . Kindly let me know if there is any mistake.

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00201: identifier 'PR_REJECT_FILE' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored

at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:330)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:287)
```

Here is my procedure call:

```
CallableStatement cs=null;

    try
    {
        cs = this.dteConn.prepareCall("{ call PR_REJECT_FILE (?,?,?) }");
        cs.setString(1,status);
        cs.setInt(2, fileid);
        cs.setString(3,t_id);
        cs.execute();

    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: check whether the user have the permission on that DB

Comment: First check if the user owns this procedure. If not check if the user have execute grant on the procedure. And third check if there is a public synonym on the procedure, otherwise you should call it SCHEMA_NAME.PR_REJECT_FILE , where schema_name is the user who owns it.

Answer (score 0):

What is the `PR_REJECT_FILE` ? I mean is it a function or a procedure? the `call` command is not for using with PL/SQL it's for using in sql*plus.
I mean you can't call a procedure or function like that you did in your code in PLSQL, it depends on the output of `PR_REJECT_FILE`and also the user or schema that owns it.

if it is procedure you can call it like this:

```
begin
PR_REJECT_FILE (?,?,?);
end;
```

if it is a function returning a scalar value you can call it like below:

```
select PR_REJECT_FILE (?,?,?) from dual;
```

If `PR_REJECT_FILE` is for another user and you have permission on executing it then you have to bring that user's prefix in above codes(`user.PR_REJECT_FILE`).

I prefer to search on using packages, procedures or functions with JDBC.

Comment: Sorry didnt add that, It is a procedure. From Java, the call will be of that syntax. I am having other proceudre calls of same syntax from java

Comment: Yea, you are right you can use it with JDBC, I remember that I have used it like that, but as I know the calling procedures in SQLPLUS is like that, not int PLSQL, in PLSQL you don't need to _call_ keyword.

Answer (score 0):

Grant execute permission on your procedure to the db username used in your Java Application.

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON PR_REJECT_FILE TO DBUsername_used_in_your_Java_Application;
```

e.g.

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON PR_REJECT_FILE TO APPDBUSERNAME;
```